# Как поменять версию java в Maven compiler?

Tags: java, maven

Как поменять версию java  в Maven compiler?
Не для конкретного проекта в POM файле, а в настройках Maven? 
У меня прописаны переменные "JAVA_HOME" и "MAVEN_HOME".
Текущая версия JAVA SDK - 9.0.4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке установить локальную библиотеку получаю ошибку "Source option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в properties добaвьте `<maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а где именно это добавить?

Comment: `<project>
.... 
  <properties>` в pom.xml file

Comment: так у меня нет POM файла, я в теме написал: "Не для конкретного проекта в POM файле, а в настройках Maven?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В домашней папке есть скрытая папка `.m2`. Она предназначена для хранения локального репозитория maven и глобальных настроек (они-то и нужны). Настройки лежат в `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`
Там уже есть какие-то настройки, скорее всего профиль. Ниже написано, какие свойства нужно добавить в активный профиль:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>...</id>
            <properties>                    
                <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
...
```

Настройки из settings.xml действительны по умолчанию. Так что если в будущих проектах не указывать эти настройки, значения версии будут подцепляться из settings.xml

Answer (score 2):

можно в pom указать версии

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Можно во время выполнения команды `mvn` добавить аргументы

```
-Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6
```

Также можно открыть файл maven/bin/mvn.bat и добавить эти аргументы после

```
".../bin/mvn -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6" "$@"
```

тогда у вас всегда будут эти версии и не нужно передавать в параметрах запуска и добавлять в pom

Comment: POM? если это идет речь про POM файл проекта, так я же сказал, что мне не для конкретного проекта это, а для компилятора

Comment: обновил ответ. посмотрите